# I closed a question by mistake. Please help me reopen it, if you agree

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

**Update:**  That was fast!  Question now reopened.

---

I voted to close this [newbie's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16942611/331508) because I misread it and did not see the subtle difference to previous questions. (Multiple links, simultaneously... *Probably* does not want to open new windows)

When I realized my mistake, I edited the question to make its difference a little clearer (I thought).  But, by that time, the close votes had started piling on.  I think it's relevant that the other four close-voters have zero score, between them, in the most relevant tag to the question ([greasemonkey](/questions/tagged/greasemonkey)).

The question does not deserve to be closed as a duplicate of the post I initially linked.

If you agree, [**please vote to reopen it**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16942611/331508). Thanks.

Comment: ...and why not just flag for mod attention?

Comment: @Yannis, I didn't just flag it because (1) I remember reading, that the moderators have a huge load and we should use the community more for tasks the community can do; and (2) there was a chance those 4 other people saw something I didn't, and I know the crowd here on meta would be sure to point it out, if that was the case.

Comment: And again, I think not being able to rescind a close vote is just silly.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles I hadn't realized you edited the question, commented and waited a couple of hours for the re-open queue to work its magic before coming to Meta (your different username threw me off). Anyway, coming to Meta is fine, I was just curious why you hadn't tried anything else before that (but of course you did).

Answer (score 1):

The question has been reopened.

Next time, the correct course of action would be to first flag for moderator, only if that doesn't work should you ask for support here on meta (no need to involve the entire community on such a very localized issue).

Have fun :)

Comment: There's not even a need to flag for a mod, just vote to reopen and it'll be put in the reopen queue which should give it enough attention.

Comment: I'd heard (and believe) the opposite.  Only bring in the heavy guns if the community fails.  And the community handled it straight away -- no need to add to the moderator workload.  I guess next time, maybe I'll try chat first.

Comment: Don't _just_ vote to reopen, comment on why it should be reopened first and improve the question as much as possible. Plus there's always chat.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, I *did* both of those!  Didn't try chat.  Chat is so sparsely attended -- especially for my normal hours -- that I tend to overlook it.